# Download from YouTube failed

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I installed youtube-dl and executing the  command it shows:

```
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] _gp51lt9kdA: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] _gp51lt9kdA: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] _gp51lt9kdA: Extracting video information

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 4645, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 4636, in main
    _real_main()
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 4620, in _real_main
    retcode = fd.download(all_urls)
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 869, in download
    ie.extract(url)
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 1135, in extract
    return self._real_extract(url)
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 1406, in _real_extract
    url_map = dict((ud['itag'][0], ud['url'][0] + '&signature=' + ud['sig'][0]) for ud in url_data)
  File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line 1406, in <genexpr>
    url_map = dict((ud['itag'][0], ud['url'][0] + '&signature=' + ud['sig'][0]) for ud in url_data)
KeyError: 'sig'
```

Comment: How did you you install it, using `apt-get` command or using a .dep package?

Comment: @G_P  I installed it using apt-get command.

Comment: Update your system and try again.

Comment: Did that fix the problem? If so, say here and @g_p can make his comment an 'Answer' and you can Accept it. If it didn't, report a bug with `ubuntu-bug youtube-dl`.

Comment: Your YouTube video can be successfully downloaded with the youtube-dl program from the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 14.04. There is no need to update youtube-dl in Ubuntu 14.04, it downloads your video successfully out of the box. This indicates that there is either a bug or some other software issue that is preventing you from downloading the video linked to in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Update youtube-dl by adding this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Then you may download any video as usual. For example ::

```
sudo youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix1rD4JD3eo
```